# firebaseを用いたSNSアプリでコメント投稿の機能を実装したい

Tags: swift, firebase, swift5

Xcode11.3
Swift5
macOSMojave10.14.6

Facebookのコメント投稿画面のような、タイムライン画面（TableView）から記事（セル）をタップし、遷移先画面でコメントを投稿できる機能を実装したいのですが、セルをタップした際に遷移先へそのセル番号(indexPath.row)を送る方法と、遷移先でセル番号を検知してFirebaseへ保存する方法がわかりません。ご教授願います。

遷移元はdidSelectRowAt内で遷移先へセル番号を送るのだと思いますが、以下で合っているのかどうかがわかりません。

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // タップされたセルの行番号を出力
        print("\(indexPath.row)番目の行が選択されました。")

        let postData = postArray[indexPath.row]

        //記事画面へ遷移（セグエ）
          let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Article") as! ArticleViewController
        //completionでSetPostDataに渡す
            self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: {
                nextVC.SetPostData(postData)
            })
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Article", sender: postArray[indexPath.row])
        //セルの選択を解除
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }
```

遷移先ではTextFieldにコメントを入力し、UIButtonを押すとUILabelに反映されるようにしたいのですが、セル番号を受信する方法がわかりません。

```swift
@IBAction func CommentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // 配列からタップされたインデックスのデータを取り出す
        let postData = HomeViewController.postArray[indexPath!.row]

        //現在の使用者の表示名がnilじゃなかったら、displayNameに代入し、
        if let displayName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName,
        //cell.textField.textがnilじゃなかったら、commentTextとする
        let commentText = self.CommentTextField.text  {

            //であれば、cell(PostTableViewCell)のtextFieldをプリントする
            print(self.CommentTextField.text as Any)

            //であれば、postData.commentsにcommentTextをappend(追加)する
            postData.comments.append("\(displayName): \(commentText)\n")

        }

        // 増えたcommentsをFirebaseに保存する
        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
        //comments辞書
        let commentDictionary = ["comments": postData.comments]
        //Firebaseに辞書を保存する
        postRef.updateChildValues(commentDictionary)       
    }
```

追記
遷移元HomeViewContoroller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var postArray: [PostData] = []

    // DatabaseのobserveEventの登録状態を表す
    var observing = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // テーブル行の高さをAutoLayoutで自動調整する
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        // テーブル行の高さの概算値を設定しておく
        // 高さ概算値 = 「縦横比1:1のUIImageViewの高さ(=画面幅)」+「いいねボタン、キャプションラベル、その他余白の高さの合計概算(=100pt)」
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 100
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: viewWillAppear")

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            if self.observing == false {
                // 要素が追加されたらpostArrayに追加してTableViewを再表示する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childAddedイベントが発生しました。")

                    // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: 0)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
                // 要素が変更されたら該当のデータをpostArrayから一度削除した後に新しいデータを追加してTableViewを再表示する
                postsRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childChangedイベントが発生しました。")

                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)

                        // 保持している配列からidが同じものを探す
                        var index: Int = 0
                        for post in self.postArray {
                            if post.id == postData.id {
                                index = self.postArray.firstIndex(of: post)!
                                break
                            }
                        }

                        // 差し替えるため一度削除する
                        self.postArray.remove(at: index)

                        // 削除したところに更新済みのデータを追加する
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: index)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより登録されたため
                // trueとする
                observing = true
            }
        } else {
            if observing == true {
                // ログアウトを検出したら、一旦テーブルをクリアしてオブザーバーを削除する。
                // テーブルをクリアする
                postArray = []
                tableView.reloadData()
                // オブザーバーを削除する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.removeAllObservers()

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより解除されたため
                // falseとする
                observing = false
            }
        }
    }
    //セルの数を決めるメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postArray.count
    }
    //セルを構築する際に呼ばれるメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // セルを取得してデータを設定する
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.setPostData(postArray[indexPath.row])

        // セル内のボタンのアクションをソースコードで設定する
        cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButton(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    //セルをタップしたら...のメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // タップされたセルの行番号を出力
        print("\(indexPath.row)番目の行が選択されました。")

        let postData = postArray[indexPath.row]

        //記事画面へ遷移（セグエ）
          let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Article") as! ArticleViewController
        //completionでSetPostDataに渡す
            self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: {
                nextVC.SetPostData(postData)
            })
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Article", sender: postArray[indexPath.row])
        //セルの選択を解除
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }

    // セル内のボタンがタップされた時に呼ばれるメソッド
    @objc func handleButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: likeボタンがタップされました。")

        // タップされたセルのインデックスを求める
        let touch = event.allTouches?.first
        let point = touch!.location(in: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        // 配列からタップされたインデックスのデータを取り出す
        let postData = postArray[indexPath!.row]

        // Firebaseに保存するデータの準備
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            if postData.isLiked {
                // すでにいいねをしていた場合はいいねを解除するためIDを取り除く
                var index = -1
                for likeId in postData.likes {
                    if likeId == uid {
                        // 削除するためにインデックスを保持しておく
                        index = postData.likes.firstIndex(of: likeId)!
                        break
                    }
                }
                postData.likes.remove(at: index)
            } else {
                postData.likes.append(uid)
            }

            // 増えたlikesをFirebaseに保存する
            let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
            let likes = ["likes": postData.likes]
            postRef.updateChildValues(likes)

        }
    }

}
```

遷移先ArticleViewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SVProgressHUD

class ArticleViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ArticleImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ArticleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ArticleButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ArticleLilkeCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.CommentTextField.delegate = self
        CommentTextField.returnKeyType = .done
    }

    func SetPostData(_ postData: PostData) {
        //イメージ画像
        self.ArticleImage.image = postData.image
        //キャプションのテキスト
        self.ArticleLabel.text = "\(postData.name!) : \(postData.caption!)"
        //いいねの数
        let likeNumber = postData.likes.count
        ArticleLilkeCount.text = "\(likeNumber)"

        //いいねボタン
        if postData.isLiked {
            let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "like_exist")
            self.ArticleButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        } else {
            let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "like_none")
            self.ArticleButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        }
        //allCommentは最初は空である
        var allComment = ""

        //postData.commentsの中から要素をひとつずつ取り出すのを繰り返す、というのがcomment
        for comment in postData.comments{
        //comment + comment = allCommentである
        allComment += comment
        //commentLabelに表示するのはallComment（commentを足していったもの）である
        self.CommentLabel.text = allComment
        }

    }

    //キーボードを閉じる
    @IBAction func textField(_ sender: Any) {
        CommentTextField.text = (sender as AnyObject).text
    }

    //コメント投稿ボタン
    @IBAction func CommentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // 配列からタップされたインデックスのデータを取り出す
        let postData = HomeViewController.postArray[indexPath!.row]

        //現在の使用者の表示名がnilじゃなかったら、displayNameに代入し、
        if let displayName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName,
        //cell.textField.textがnilじゃなかったら、commentTextとする
        let commentText = self.CommentTextField.text  {

            //であれば、cell(PostTableViewCell)のtextFieldをプリントする
            print(self.CommentTextField.text as Any)

            //であれば、postData.commentsにcommentTextをappend(追加)する
            postData.comments.append("\(displayName): \(commentText)\n")

        }

        // 増えたcommentsをFirebaseに保存する
        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
        //comments辞書
        let commentDictionary = ["comments": postData.comments]
        //Firebaseに辞書を保存する
        postRef.updateChildValues(commentDictionary)     
    }
}
```

Comment: 正直言って、コードの断片だけ見せられても何をどのようにアドバイスするべきかわからないと言うのが正直なところです。「タイムライン画面」と言うのはどのクラスですか? 「遷移先画面」はどのクラス? `postArray`はどのクラスでどのように宣言されていますか? `SetPostData`なんてメソッドはどこに定義されているのですか? 画面遷移には`present(_:animated:completion)`メソッドを使うのですか、それともセグエを使うのですか? `HomeViewController`とはどのクラスのことですか、`HomeViewController.postArray`はどのように定義されているのですか? …そう言った関連事項の諸々を全てご質問に含んでいただいた方が、より具体的な回答が書きやすくなるので、より的確な回答をより早く得られることにつながるでしょう。ご自身の質問は「編集」と書かれたリンクから修正することができますので、是非必要な情報を付け加えてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。それぞれのViewControllerを追記しました。遷移はセグエです。

Comment: 情報の追記ありがとうございます。だいぶ不明点が解消されましたので、回答をまとめてみたいと思います。しばらくお待ち下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この回答は、ご質問内の ***以下で合っているのかどうかがわかりません*** および、***セル番号を受信する方法がわかりません*** と言う2つの疑問点についてのものです。

その他の部分(例えばFirebaseにデータを保存する方法やら、強制アンラップ(`!`)の使い方が適切かどうか)等については触れていませんので、ご注意ください。

また、view controller間のデータの受け渡しでは極めて重要となる情報 ***遷移はセグエです*** と言うのに全面的に依拠しています。

---

#### データを送る側

- 「遷移はセグエ」であれば、`prepare(for:sender:)`を実装して、その中でデータを渡します。
- 「遷移はセグエ」なのに、`present(_:animated:completion:)`を呼んではいけません
- `present`を使う場合でも、(普通)`completion`の中でデータの受け渡しを行うことはしません

と言う訳で、`HomeViewController`の`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`の辺りは例えば、次のようになるでしょう。

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //...


    //セルをタップしたら...のメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // タップされたセルの行番号を出力
        print("\(indexPath.row)番目の行が選択されました。")

        let postData = postArray[indexPath.row]

        //記事画面へ遷移（セグエ）→セグエで遷移するならインスタンスを作成したり、`present`を呼んだりしない
//          let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Article") as! ArticleViewController
//        //completionでSetPostDataに渡す
//            self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: {
//                nextVC.SetPostData(postData)
//            })
        postDataToSend = postData
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Article", sender: tableView)
        //セルの選択を解除
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }

    var postDataToSend: PostData?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Article" {
            let nextVC = segue.destination as! ArticleViewController
            if let postData = postDataToSend {
                nextVC.setPostData(postData)
            }
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

---

#### データを受け取る側

- データを受け取るための変数を用意します
- その変数に設定されたデータは`viewWillAppear(_:)`の中などで画面等に反映します

これを反映すると、以下のようなコードになるでしょう。

```
class ArticleViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //...

    //前画面からデータを受け取るための変数
    var postDataReceived: PostData?

    func setPostData(_ postData: PostData) {
        postDataReceived = postData
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }
        //イメージ画像
        self.articleImage.image = postData.image
        //キャプションのテキスト
        self.articleLabel.text = "\(postData.name!) : \(postData.caption!)"
        //いいねの数
        let likeNumber = postData.likes.count
        articleLilkeCount.text = "\(likeNumber)"

        //いいねボタン
        if postData.isLiked {
            let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "like_exist")
            self.articleButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        } else {
            let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "like_none")
            self.articleButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        }
        //allCommentは最初は空である
        var allComment = ""

        //postData.commentsの中から要素をひとつずつ取り出すのを繰り返す、というのがcomment
        for comment in postData.comments{
            //comment + comment = allCommentである
            allComment += comment
            //commentLabelに表示するのはallComment（commentを足していったもの）である
            self.commentLabel.text = allComment
        }

    }

    //...


    //コメント投稿ボタン
    @IBAction func commentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // 前画面から受け取ったデータを取り出す
        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }

        //...

    }

    //...

}
```

- Swiftでは大文字スタートの識別子は型名だけに使う、と言うルールが大変よく守られています。あなたの現在のコードは非常に読みにくいので、一部書き換えてあります。
- ネット上の記事によっては「データを受け取る側」の処理を`viewDidLoad()`で行う、と紹介しているものがありますが、ちょっとした不注意で正しく動かなくなるので、`viewWillAppear(_:)`を使用しています。
- ご質問内では「セル番号を送る/受信する」とされていますが、`postArray`はインスタンスプロパティなので`HomeViewController.postArray`なんて形で簡単に「データを取り出す」ことができません。よって、この回答では「セル番号」(インデックス)ではなく、データそのものを渡すようにしてあります。

---

データの受け渡しに話を絞っているので、何かしらうまくいかない点が出てくるかもしれません。その場合にはコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 遅くまで申し訳ございません。詳細なご説明ありがとうございます。ボタンの部分ではよくないところはございますか？

Comment: 「ボタンの部分で」と言うのは具体的にどの部分のことでしょうか? とりあえず、`commentButton(_:)`については、お示しするのを忘れていた部分があるので追加しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。commentButton(_:)についてで大丈夫です。追記で質問よろしいでしょうか。

Comment: すいません。あとはなんとかなりそうです。色々ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。