# 記事ごとのFirebase孫データの取得ができず、全ての記事で同じコメントが表示されてしまう。

Tags: firebase, swift5

Xcode11.3
Swift5
macOSMojave10.14.6

## 実現したいことと

フェイスブックのコメントボタンを押した時のような、UITableViewを使用したタイムライン画面(HomeViewController)から個別の画面(ArticleViewController)に遷移（画像１）
↓
(ArticleViewContorollerの)TextFieldにコメントを入力後、投稿ボタンを押すと、遷移前のタイムライン画面（HomeViewController）でタップしたセルと同じセル番号にコメント文がFirebase(commnets)に追加され（画像２）、遷移後の画面(ArticleViewController)にあるテーブルビュー（commentTableView,CommentTableViewCell）にコメントが表示される
↓
別のユーザーがコメント投稿するごとに下に増えていく
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 困っていること

Farebaseにはタイムラインの記事ごとにコメントが格納されますが、そこからカスタムセル（CommenTabaleViewCell）で記事ごとのコメントデータを表示せず、全てのコメントが表示されてしまい、他の記事を表示しても同じコメントになってしまいます。
ArticleViewControllerからCommentTableViewCellへのindexPathの渡し方が悪いと思いますが、ご教授願います。
[image: firebaseには]
firebaseには孫データ（comments）が反映されています。

**タイムライン画面**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var postArray: [PostData] = []

    // DatabaseのobserveEventの登録状態を表す
    var observing = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // テーブル行の高さを165
        tableView.rowHeight = 165
        // テーブル行の高さの概算値を設定しておく
        // 高さ概算値 = 「縦横比1:1のUIImageViewの高さ(=画面幅)」+「いいねボタン、キャプションラベル、その他余白の高さの合計概算(=100pt)」
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: viewWillAppear")

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            if self.observing == false {
                // 要素が追加されたらpostArrayに追加してTableViewを再表示する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childAddedイベントが発生しました。")

                    // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: 0)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
                // 要素が変更されたら該当のデータをpostArrayから一度削除した後に新しいデータを追加してTableViewを再表示する
                postsRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childChangedイベントが発生しました。")

                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)

                        // 保持している配列からidが同じものを探す
                        var index: Int = 0
                        for post in self.postArray {
                            if post.id == postData.id {
                                index = self.postArray.firstIndex(of: post)!
                                break
                            }
                        }

                        // 差し替えるため一度削除する
                        self.postArray.remove(at: index)

                        // 削除したところに更新済みのデータを追加する
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: index)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより登録されたため
                // trueとする
                observing = true
            }
        } else {
            if observing == true {
                // ログアウトを検出したら、一旦テーブルをクリアしてオブザーバーを削除する。
                // テーブルをクリアする
                postArray = []
                tableView.reloadData()
                // オブザーバーを削除する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.removeAllObservers()

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより解除されたため
                // falseとする
                observing = false
            }
        }
    }
    //セルの数を決めるメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postArray.count
    }
    //セルを構築する際に呼ばれるメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // セルを取得してデータを設定する
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.setPostData(postArray[indexPath.row])

        // セル内のボタンのアクションをソースコードで設定する
        cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButton(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    //セルをタップしたら...のメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // タップされたセルの行番号を出力
        print("\(indexPath.row)番目の行が選択されました。")

        let postData = postArray[indexPath.row]

        postDataToSend = postData
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Article", sender: nil)
            //セルの選択を解除
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        }

        var postDataToSend: PostData?

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "Article" {
                let nextVC = segue.destination as! ArticleViewController
                if let postData = postDataToSend {
                    nextVC.setPostData(postData)
                }
            }
    }

    // セル内のボタンがタップされた時に呼ばれるメソッド
    @objc func handleButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: likeボタンがタップされました。")

        // タップされたセルのインデックスを求める
        let touch = event.allTouches?.first
        let point = touch!.location(in: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        // 配列からタップされたインデックスのデータを取り出す
        let postData = postArray[indexPath!.row]

        // Firebaseに保存するデータの準備
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            if postData.isLiked {
                // すでにいいねをしていた場合はいいねを解除するためIDを取り除く
                var index = -1
                for likeId in postData.likes {
                    if likeId == uid {
                        // 削除するためにインデックスを保持しておく
                        index = postData.likes.firstIndex(of: likeId)!
                        break
                    }
                }
                postData.likes.remove(at: index)
            } else {
                postData.likes.append(uid)
            }

            // 増えたlikesをFirebaseに保存する
            let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
            let likes = ["likes": postData.likes]
            postRef.updateChildValues(likes)

        }
    }   
}
```

**コメント投稿画面**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SVProgressHUD

class ArticleViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var articleImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var articleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var articleButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var articleLilkeCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

    var postArray: [PostData] = []
    //textFieldが動くようにする
    private var activeTextField: UITextField?

    //前画面からデータを受け取るための変数
    var postDataReceived: PostData?

    // DatabaseのobserveEventの登録状態を表す
    var observing = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        commentTableView.delegate = self
        commentTableView.dataSource = self
        // テーブルセルのタップを無効にする
        commentTableView.allowsSelection = false

        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CommentTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        commentTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")

        // テーブル行の高さをAutoLayoutで自動調整する
        commentTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        // テーブル行の高さの概算値を設定しておく
        // 高さ概算値 = 「縦横比1:1のUIImageViewの高さ(=画面幅)」+「いいねボタン、キャプションラベル、その他余白の高さの合計概算(=100pt)」
        commentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        //イメージ画像
        self.articleImage.image = postData.image
        //キャプションのテキスト
        self.articleLabel.text = "\(postData.caption!)"
        //いいねの数
        let likeNumber = postData.likes.count
        articleLilkeCount.text = "\(likeNumber)"


        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            if self.observing == false {
                // 要素が追加されたらpostArrayに追加してTableViewを再表示する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childAddedイベントが発生しました。")

                    // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: 0)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.commentTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
                // 要素が変更されたら該当のデータをpostArrayから一度削除した後に新しいデータを追加してTableViewを再表示する
                postsRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
                    print("DEBUG_PRINT: .childChangedイベントが発生しました。")

                    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        // PostDataクラスを生成して受け取ったデータを設定する
                        let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)

                        // 保持している配列からidが同じものを探す
                        var index: Int = 0
                        for post in self.postArray {
                            if post.id == postData.id {
                                index = self.postArray.firstIndex(of: post)!
                                break
                            }
                        }

                        // 差し替えるため一度削除する
                        self.postArray.remove(at: index)

                        // 削除したところに更新済みのデータを追加する
                        self.postArray.insert(postData, at: index)

                        // TableViewを再表示する
                        self.commentTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより登録されたため
                // trueとする
                observing = true
            }
        } else {
            if observing == true {
                // ログアウトを検出したら、一旦テーブルをクリアしてオブザーバーを削除する。
                // テーブルをクリアする
                postArray = []
                commentTableView.reloadData()
                // オブザーバーを削除する
                let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath)
                postsRef.removeAllObservers()

                // DatabaseのobserveEventが上記コードにより解除されたため
                // falseとする
                observing = false
            }
        }

        //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
        self.commentTextField.delegate = self
        self.setUpNotificationForTextField()
    }
    func setPostData(_ postData: PostData) {
        postDataReceived = postData
    }
    //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
    internal func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
           textField.resignFirstResponder()
           return true
       }
    //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
    internal func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.activeTextField = textField
        return true
    }
    //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
     internal func setUpNotificationForTextField() {
           let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
           notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
           notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
       }
    //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
    @objc private func handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo //この中にキーボードの情報がある
        let keyboardSize = (userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let keyboardY = self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height //画面全体の高さ - キーボードの高さ = キーボードが被らない高さ
        let editingTextFieldY: CGFloat = (self.activeTextField?.frame.origin.y)!
        if editingTextFieldY > keyboardY - 60 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - (editingTextFieldY - (keyboardY - 60)), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }
    //textFieldがキーボードで隠れないようにする
    @objc private func handleKeyboardWillHideNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    //コメントテーブルビュー
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return postArray.count
       }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       // セルを取得してデータを設定する
       let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
       cell2.commentSetPostData(postArray[indexPath.row])

        //テキストを初期化
        cell2.commentLabel.text = nil

       // セル内のボタンのアクションをソースコードで設定する
       cell2.goodButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleGoodButton(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)

       return cell2
    }
    //コメント投稿ボタン
    @IBAction func commentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // 前画面から受け取ったデータを取り出す
        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }

        //cell.textField.textがnilじゃなかったら、commentTextとする
        if let commentText = self.commentTextField.text  {

            //であれば、cell(PostTableViewCell)のtextFieldをプリントする
            print(self.commentTextField.text as Any)

            //であれば、postData.commentsにcommentTextをappend(追加)する
            postData.comments.append("\(commentText)\n")
        }

        // 増えたcommentsをFirebaseに保存する
        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
        //comments辞書
        let commentDictionary = ["comments": postData.comments]
        //Firebaseに辞書を保存する
        postRef.updateChildValues(commentDictionary)
    }

    // セル内のボタンがタップされた時に呼ばれるメソッド
    @objc func handleGoodButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: goodボタンがタップされました。")

        // タップされたセルのインデックスを求める
        let touch = event.allTouches?.first
        let point = touch!.location(in: self.commentTableView)
        let indexPath = commentTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        // 配列からタップされたインデックスのデータを取り出す
        let postData = postArray[indexPath!.row]

        // Firebaseに保存するデータの準備
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            if postData.isLiked2 {
                // すでにいいねをしていた場合はいいねを解除するためIDを取り除く
                var index = -1
                for likeId in postData.likes2 {
                    if likeId == uid {
                        // 削除するためにインデックスを保持しておく
                        index = postData.likes2.firstIndex(of: likeId)!
                        break
                    }
                }
                postData.likes2.remove(at: index)
            } else {
                postData.likes2.append(uid)
            }

            // 増えたgoodをFirebaseに保存する
            let postRef = Database.database().reference().child(Const.PostPath).child(postData.id!)
            let goods = ["likes2": postData.likes2]
            postRef.updateChildValues(goods)

        }
    }
}
```

**カスタムセル**

```
class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goodButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    //前画面からデータを受け取るための変数
    var postDataReceived: PostData?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func commentSetPostData(_ postData: PostData) {
        postDataReceived = postData

        //postData.commentsの中から要素をひとつずつ取り出すのを繰り返す、というのがcomment
        for comment in postData.comments{
            //commentLabelに表示するのはcomment
            self.commentLabel.text = comment
        }
    }
}
```

**ポストデータ**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class PostData: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var imageString: String?
    var name: String?
    var caption: String?
    var comments : [String] = []
    var date: Date?
    var likes: [String] = []
    var isLiked: Bool = false
    var likes2: [String] = []
    var isLiked2: Bool = false

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot, myId: String) {
        self.id = snapshot.key

        let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        //投稿画像
        imageString = valueDictionary["image"] as? String
        image = UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: imageString!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!)
        //投稿者の名前
        self.name = valueDictionary["name"] as? String
        //キャプション
        self.caption = valueDictionary["caption"] as? String
        //コメント
        if let comments = valueDictionary["comments"] as? [String] {
            self.comments = comments
        }
        //日付
        let time = valueDictionary["time"] as? String
        self.date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval(time!)!)
        // いいねボタン
        if let likes = valueDictionary["likes"] as? [String] {
            self.likes = likes
        }
        for likeId in self.likes {
            if likeId == myId {
                self.isLiked = true
                break
            }
        }
        // いいねボタン2
        if let likes = valueDictionary["likes2"] as? [String] {
            self.likes2 = likes
        }
        for likeId in self.likes2 {
            if likeId == myId {
                self.isLiked2 = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**コンスト**

```
import Foundation

struct Const {
    static let PostPath = "posts"
}
```

Comment: さて、あなたのご質問文の記述とあなたのコードがどうも矛盾しているように思います。「タイムライン画面」「遷移前」と言うのが[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62191/13972)にコードを掲載されている`HomeViewContoroller`、「個別の画面」「遷移後のページ」「コメント投稿画面」と言うは皆同じもので`ArticleViewController`を指していると言うことで良いのでしょうか? だとすると`ArticleViewController`の`tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`や`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`は`postArray`、つまりタイムラインの内容を表示するようにコーティングされています。本文からすると`ArticleViewController`のテーブルには`postDataReceived.comments`を表示しないといけないのではないですか?Firebase側の設定、データ例などわかる情報を追記してくださったようですが、それに対してどんな画面になるべきなのをわかりやすく示していただけるともう少し具体的な話ができるかもしれません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問の仕方すらままならず申し訳ございません。そもそもの基本がなってないためにご不便をおかけしております。本文の修正をしました。前々回の質問でOOPerさんにご回答いただいた物を改変した物になります。

Comment: postDataReceived.commentsを使うと`Value of optional type 'PostData?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'comments' of wrapped base type 'PostData'`や`alue of type '[String]' has no member 'comments'`といったエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: postArrayをどうすればpostDataReceived.commentsにすることができますか？

Comment: postArrayは結局PostDataで、PostDataを抜きにしてpostDataReceived.commentsというのを作ることができません。commentsをPostDataクラスから独立させた方が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 多忙でコメントを返せず失礼しました。さて、先に書いたように現在のあなたのコードの`postArray`は「タイムライン中の全記事」です。「コメント画面」で必要なのは、「タイムライン画面で選択された特定の記事」だけであるはずです。とりあえずtableViewにコメントを表示する、と言うことだけに注目した回答を書いてみますので、出来ましたら参考にしてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

さて、コメントでは少し端折って書いてしまいましたが、あなたが「コメント投稿画面」内のtableViewにコメントの一覧を表示したいのであれば、

- `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`ではコメントの数を返す
- `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`では`indexPath`番目のコメントをセットしたcellを返す

と言うことが必要です。

また「コメント投稿画面」内でタイムライン全体を保持する必要はありません。

そこら辺を踏まえてあなたのコードを書き直すと、こんな感じになります。

(削除すべきところをわかりやすくするために、コメントアウトしているだけの部分がありますが、不要ですのでさっくり削除してください。)

#### コメント投稿画面

```
class ArticleViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //...

    //### この画面で「タイムラインの記事」全部を保持する必要はない
    //var postArray: [PostData] = []

    //...

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }

        //### この画面でタイムライン全体を監視しても意味が無い。監視するとしたら`postData`だけを監視する

        //イメージ画像
        self.articleImage.image = postData.image
        //キャプションのテキスト
        self.articleLabel.text = "\(postData.caption!)"
        //いいねの数
        let likeNumber = postData.likes.count
        articleLilkeCount.text = "\(likeNumber)"
    }

    //...

    //コメントテーブルビュー
    //### コメントをtableViewに表示するのであれば、ここで「コメントの数」を返さないといけない
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //`postDataReceived`がnilの時に呼ばれる可能性もあるので、条件付きバインディングで判定
        if let postData = postDataReceived {
            return postData.comments.count  //コメントの数を返す
        } else {
            return 0  //`postDataReceived`がnilなら0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // セルを取得してデータを設定する
        //### セルのIDには意味のあるわかりやすい名前をつけましょう
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell

        //### `postDataReceived`がnilの時に呼ばれる可能性もあるので、条件付きバインディングで判定
        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return cell
        }
        //### コメント用セルには、コメントに関する情報を渡さないといけない、記事全体ではない
        //cell.commentSetPostData(postData)

        //テキストを初期化
        //### `indexPath`番目のコメントを設定
        cell.commentLabel.text = postData.comments[indexPath.row]

        //### セル内のUI要素にアクションを設定する場合、古いアクションをクリアしないといけない
        cell.goodButton.removeTarget(self, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
        // セル内のボタンのアクションをソースコードで設定する
        cell.goodButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleGoodButton(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    //...


    // セル内のボタンがタップされた時に呼ばれるメソッド
    @objc func handleGoodButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("DEBUG_PRINT: goodボタンがタップされました。")

        //### ここでevent.allTouchesから位置を求めても「Goodボタンの位置」が取れるだけ
        // タップされたセルのインデックスを求める
        //let touch = event.allTouches?.first
        //let point = touch!.location(in: self.commentTableView)
        //let indexPath = commentTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        //### この画面で表示されている記事のデータを取り出す
        guard let postData = postDataReceived else {
            return
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

#### カスタムセル

```
class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goodButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    //### 不要
    //前画面からデータを受け取るための変数
    //var postDataReceived: PostData?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    //### `self.commentLabel.text`内容をループ内で次々に入れ替えても意味はない
//    func commentSetPostData(_ postData: PostData) {
//        postDataReceived = postData
//
//        //postData.commentsの中から要素をひとつずつ取り出すのを繰り返す、というのがcomment
//        for comment in postData.comments{
//            //commentLabelに表示するのはcomment
//            self.commentLabel.text = comment
//        }
//    }
}
```

---

`Value of optional type 'PostData?' must be unwrapped ...`なんてエラーをご自身で解決できない状態ということは、まだSwift言語の基本中の基本である`Optional`型の扱いが全くわかっていないと言うことになります。

「いろんなサイトの記事をコピペしてつなぎ合わせて、よくわからないままコンパイルだけ通るようにする」なんてことをしているだけでは、どこにでもあるサンプルコード以上のものを作れるようにはなりません。

App Storeにあげられるようなアプリを作りたいのであれば、きちんとSwift言語の基礎から学習し直すことをお勧めします。

---

なお、上記のコードは「とりあえずtableViewにコメントを表示する」だけのものです。コードのコメント中に書いた「`postData`だけを監視する」コードはご自身で調べて追加してみてください。

Comment: ちゃんと表示なりました！ここまでわかりやすく添削していただき、ありがとうございます。お時間を取らせて申し訳ありませんでした。仰る通りです基礎から学び直します。

Comment: goodのカウントが表示されなかったり、投稿ボタンを押してすぐにテーブルにコメントが反映されないのは「postDataだけを監視する」と関係ありますか？

Comment: もちろん関係があります。Firebase側から変更を受け取ってそれを画面に反映するようなコードを書かない限りコメント投稿画面の内容は変化しません。

Comment: おそらく.ChildAdded、.ChildAddedを使うのだと思いますが、Firebaseのドキュメントを参考にしても、その使用目的の説明があっても「この部分には何を入れる」、といったことが示されておらず、よくわかりません。fowRow:やinSection:とは何ですか？

Comment: 「おそらく.ChildAdded、.ChildAddedを使うのだと思います」と言うのがそもそもどんな根拠に基づくものだかよくわかりませんが、私が短時間で探しただけでも[こんな記事](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?hl=ja#listen_for_value_events)が公式ドキュメント中に見つかりました。とてもわかりやすい・使いやすいとは言えないドキュメントですが、記事中の単語を使って再度検索しなおせば、もっと具体的なコードとともに解説した記事も見つかります。`fowRow:`と言う`inSection:`単語は私の回答中には出てきません。ご質問の際はコードの断片だけ取ってくるのでなく、どの部分の何を聞きたいのかもう少し分かりやすうご提示をお願いします。コメントスペースだけでは書きにくいのであれば、新たに別質問とされた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ここまで親身になってご指導いただいてたいへん恐縮です。私に不足してるのはググり力と質問表現力という致命的なものと認識しています。また別枠で質問させていただきます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。その辺の力を向上させた方が「より的確な回答がより早く見つかる」と言うことは言えますが、現在でも全然致命的ではないと思いますよ。特に「自分の力(ネット上の記事や書籍を参考にするのも含めて)でどこまで出来ているか」をきちんと示せていること、質問についたコメントに対して、返信を書いたり質問文を編集したりなどをきちんとレスポンスしているなど、質問者みんなに身につけて欲しいマナーがきちんと出来ていますし。ググっただけで何もかも見つかるものなら質問サイトなんて必要ない訳ですし、「表現」なんてものは慣れていけば(もちろんいろんなコメントを参考にして)どんどん改善されていくものです。いろいろ偉そうな物言いになっているところは「より的確な回答がより早く」得るためのヒント程度に思って、良いアプリづくりにつなげていってください。